# Hide popup window when debugging

Tags: wpf, debugging, popup, hide, breakpoints

When I hit a break point whilst a popup window has its "IsOpen" property set to true, it renders on top of visual studio, obscuring the code I'm trying to step through.

Is there anyway I can resolve this?

Ive tried detecting when a break point is hit by subscribing to the main windows deactivated event, but it doesn't get called in this case.

Comment: A known issue. The only way I know to overcome it is to use dual screens - run-time on one screen, VS on another. Would love to hear if there's another solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can set conditional logic to do certain tasks if the application is running in debug mode.

```
#if DEBUG
  //Logic to hide popup
#endif
```

[See this article for full details.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx)